# Black Screen On Safari when working with pixel manipulation

Tags: canvas, webrtc, pixel, image-manipulation, mediastream

I'm working on canvas with two layer which is one over the other. I'm having video from the video, I'm trying to get the stream using drawImage in a canvas, and that video is coming from another peer so it will be in the media stream and I'm using draw Image, I got that media stream in my canvas. I'm making this canvas as transparency. For that

```
  passctx.drawImage($this, 0, 0);
  var imageData = passctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);
  var data = imageData.data;

  var removeBlack = function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
          f (data[i] + data[i + 1] + data[i + 2] <10) {
              data[i + 3] = 0; // alpha
          }
      }
      passctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  };
  //removing the alpha channel from the canvas
  removeBlack();[enter image description here][1]
```

This works fine with Chrome, Opera and Firefox, these all receive only objects/diagrams in canvas without the black screen but not on safari it still returning the media stream with a black screen. Help will be greatly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6eLF.jpg)

Comment: Weird, they do support it from their own MediaStream. What version of Safari are you using?

Comment: I'm using 11.1.2 version and I'm getting the media stream to canvas using drawImage @Kaiido

Comment: I have added screenshots also, Its coming but only around the drawings.

Comment: Ah the ios version... Can't test, but your screenshot indicates it's a bug => file a bug report.